# Unable to generate id for dynamically added table rows - Django dynamic formset

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, inline-formset

I am trying to implement Django inline formset (with a parent and child scenario) with an option to add rows for the child fields housed in a table.

For the purpose I am using [Django dynamic formset][1] which is working in so far as the default form layout is concerned as well as adding new rows at runtime. I am able to save and edit data as well, **even with the new rows added**. However I find, to my dismay, that the id's of the newly added row elements are not generated (when viewed in "view source") - actually **there are no reference to the newly added elements at all**. Am I missing something or is this the wrong way to go for what I am trying to do, considering that the plugin is pretty "**old**" and by the looks of it, there has not been much activity on the source page. (I found one user asking whether the plugin **may be used with Django 2.0!**)

The reason I want the id's of individual field elements is, that I need to carry out calculations involving values contained, using jQuery before I submit the form. Without the id's I can not pick up the input fields' values and I am stuck. To overcome the problem, I tried to generate the id's using the `forloop` contained in my template but this is a measure good for only the **default (initial) number of rows**. I don't know a way to **generate id's** post page load - I tried to get around to it but I am not sure if this can achieved dynamically, once the page has already loaded.

Is there a possibility of generating the id's after the page is loaded (using jQuery or any other means)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/docs/usage.rst), it looks like you can define a function that will be called when a new form is added. Within that, you can add an id or class or depending on your business logic, do the actual calculations.

```
    $('#myFormsetTable tbody tr').formset({
        added: function(row) {}
    });
```

Comment: As suggested by you (and the docs), I tried to add the formset option ('added'). Please check my edit (Edit 1 in the main question). Could you please look into it and clarify as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What you used is not valid javascript syntax. It should be `added: function(row) {roAdded(row)}`

Comment: I have replaced the code line 'added:   'function(roAdded(row))' ' WITH 'added: function(row) {roAdded(row)} '.  **BUT** I am not able to hit the function ('roAdded') i.e. not getting getting any alert.

Comment: What is happening then?

Comment: Absolutely nothing.  The rows are getting added as expected but (as I presume) the **added**  opt should be calling the function **roAdded(row)** and the browser should give an **alert** , is **not happening**.

Comment: I am sorry but now it's working!! The problem with my code was that it should have been this : `added: function(row) {roAdded('.formset_row')}`. And not `added: function(row) {roAdded(row)}`.  As I have shown in my formset code above, I am using a **class** `formset_row` for the table rows and that is what I should have been using.

Comment: Can you please modify your answer above so that I may accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I should change it. The code I included is from what the docs suggest, it was never supposed to be a plug-and-play solution for your code.